# Google search images in React.JS Application

Tags: reactjs, google-custom-search

I have a search bar in my application. When I search a name in the search bar, I want to show the google image search results in my application. Then I need to select few images from the results and put/copy them into another section in my application. I know I have to it using Google Custom Search API. But I am not able to implement it as I am not able to get a good implementation example for reactjs application. How should I implement it?